# $E\subset C[0,1]$ closed with functions of $C^1$ is finite dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to prove that if $E$ is a closed linear subspace of $C[0,1]$ and the elements of $E$ are functions of class $C^1$, then $E$ is finite dimensional. I have tried to prove that the unit ball in $E$ is compact, but I don't know how to do it. Can somebody help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: What is $E$? Just a subset?

Comment: Sorry, it's a linear subspace. I forgot it.

Comment: @JN_2605 What is your norm?

Comment: The norm of the maximum $||f||=\max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$